# Whats the meaning of sambaNTPassword in a machine account?

Tags: ldap, samba, password, accounts

After running samba3 for quite some time I was wondering what the exact meaning of sambaNTPassword in a samba machine account in the LDAP Database is. I never set it myself (Samba must have set it, maybe on joining the machine?) and it seems to be different for each machine account.  What is the meaning of this value?

Answer (score 2):

It's the machine account password; it's set when the machine joins the domain and (apparently) changes periodically. That's about all I know, and references are hard to come by.

Comment: That's about it. Every account, even a computer account, needs some way to authenticate and passwords are about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Well that's about what I expected from this ldap field. But I thought maybe theres some hidden magic I should know of and as you already stated information on these topics is rare and hard to find.